How to convert a string into camel case with JavaScript regex without apostrophe and white space?
I am struggling on how to convert a string into camel case without apostrophe and white space. Here is my code so far:
function toCamelCase(input) {
  return input
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/['\W]+(.)?/g, (_, char) => (char ? char.toUpperCase() : ""))
    .replace(/^./, (char) => char.toLowerCase());
}

const result2 = toCamelCase("HEy, world");
console.log(result2); // "heyWorld"

const result3 = toCamelCase("Yes, that's my student");
console.log(result3); // "yesThatsMyStudent"

""HEy, world"" works. The problem is that it is failing on "Yes, that's my student". I got "yesThatSMyStudent" instead of "yesThatsMyStudent". I have no idea why the "s" in "that's" is not lowercase. Can someone please explain why this is happening and point me in the right direction? Thank you.
Edit: Just for educational purpose, how would you handle a case if a word is quoted? For example, Yes, that's my 'student' should be yesThatsMyStudent.

What if your input contains apostrophes used as quotes, like Yes, that's my 'student'?

You could assert not ' before matching an optional char a-z


function toCamelCase(input) {
  return input
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\W+((?<!')[a-z])?/g, (_, char) => (char ? char.toUpperCase() : ""))
    .replace(/^./, (char) => char.toLowerCase());
}

const result2 = toCamelCase("HEy, world");
console.log(result2); // "heyWorld"

const result3 = toCamelCase("Yes, that's my student");
console.log(result3); // "yesThatsMyStudent"




@RavinderSingh13 Hi there! All is well? Yes I spend less time on SO, I saw it too late but I think I would eventually arrive at an answer like anubhava's regex with a shortened version of your initial pattern.

One could describe a pattern which looks for every word boundary followed by any sequence of non-letter but also non-single-quote characters which gets preceded by a single captured letter (/\b[^\p{L}']+(\p{L})/ug). This matching pattern gets entirely replace by the uppercase variant of the captured letter. One then just needs to go after every remaining non-letter and non-number character (sequence) that each will be entirely removed /[^\p{L}\p{N}]/ug ...


function toCamelCase(value) {
  return String(value)

    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/VQWTVY/1]
    .replace(/\b[^\p{L}']+(\p{L})/ug, (_, char) => char.toUpperCase())

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/VQWTVY/2]
    .replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/ug, '');
}

const result1 = toCamelCase('HEy, world');
console.log(result1); // 'heyWorld'

const result2 = toCamelCase("Yes, that's my student");
console.log(result2); // 'yesThatsMyStudent'
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }



